# Toggle CSS hidden table rows with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-tables

I have the following defined in an inline css style:

```
    tr.submission { display: none; }
    tr.submission.can_submit { display: table-row; }
    tr.submission.graded { display: table-row; }
    tr.submission.comments { display: table-row; }
```

A script generates the HTML file with the inline and tags certain rows with the table-row visibility to show them.  I would like to include a link on my page so that clicking it would toggle the tr.submission display on and off again at will, much like I can do with browser dev tools.

I'm not a JS guy, so looking for the most straight forward method that isn't going to require me reworking the above formats considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a JavaScript and use JQuery for easier call

1. Import the JQuery with CDN into your code like this below your body tag

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

2. Copy this code below the JQuery

`<script> $('.button').on('click', function () { $("tr.submission").toggle() }); </script>`

The `.button` reference to your link that clicking it would toggle the `tr.submission display`. It is like CSS so call it with `#button` if your link has an `id="button"`

Comment: So this will toggle the entire CSS for `tr.submission` on and off?  I suppose that will work in this case, though it would be good to know how to granularly just change the visibility property.  Also, I've re-read your last 2 sentences 20 times and I don't grasp what you are trying to say.  I create an anchor link with an `id="button"`, but I don't see where `#button` plays in, am I meant to just append that to my link?

Comment: Anyways I made some changes to the code I'm sorry. You can visit the jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for more information about how `.toggle()` function works.

The `#button` placed on `$('.button)` that I made before so you can write the function into this:

`<script> $('#button').on('click', function () { $("tr.submission").toggle() }); </script>`